# How to rotate an image without changing its size?

Tags: image, imagemagick

When an image is rotated by `convert -rotate` command the image size is enlarged. Is there a way to rotate around the center and to keep the image size, cropping the edges?

Answer (score 29):

```
convert image.jpg -distort SRT -45 rotate_cropped_image.png
```

See http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/warping/#animations

Example: [image: Animated GIF]

See also help on -distort: http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php?#distort

Comment: result is not what a user would expect from rotating an image.

Comment: Since the image dimensions are the same and the colored region inside the image area is the same, the file size should be the same, shouldn't? I tried this on a binary image having 13kb and the result has more than 20kb.

Comment: @Sigur Wrong. Animated gif use some sort of compression. For example it can use only difference between frames. It is cause different size for different frame order. If you try convert usual gif to animated gif then size increased because need store every frame.

Comment: @Enyby, sorry. My mistake. I was talking about rotating a single image file. No gifs.

Comment: @Sigur All same for rotate any compressed image. Only bmp do not compressed. All other format use compression. Compression can give different result even if all pixels stay same but reordered. This is flip case. In all other cases pixels changed - any rotation on custom angle change all pixels. It cause different size. It can be smaller or larger.

Comment: dont forget to convert to png.

Answer (score 4):

This seems now to simply "just work" -- for counter-clockwise 90 degrees:

```
$ convert image.jpg -rotate -90 rotated_ccw.jpg
```

Comment: Wrong answer. Because author want keep image size and crop the edges.

Answer (score 3):

If you know the size of the image the following works:

```
convert -rotate 45 -gravity center -crop NxN input output
```

tested with square images.
there may be a way to specify NxN is the input image size.

Answer (score 0):

I've found this answer on Imagemagick forum:

A simple solution without knowing what the original size of the image
was, is to use the Alpha Composite Operator 'Src' as a 'crop to this
image size' type of operation. See:

http://www.cit.gu.edu.au/~anthony/graphics/imagick6/compose/#src

For example  (ImageMagick version 6 only):

```
convert image.jpg \( +clone -background black -rotate -45 \) \
    -gravity center -compose Src -composite rotate_cropped_image.png
```

Comment: image is rotated, but top and bottom from original is now cut off... not a good result